# Is there a way to merge Word documents with track changes?

Tags: python, ms-word, openxml, python-docx, aspose

Microsoft Word enables users to merge two documents with track changes (revisions), resulting in a document that encompasses both sets of revisions. You can find more details on this feature in the official Microsoft Office support documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/combine-document-revisions-f8f07f09-4461-4376-b041-89ad67412cfe).

Is there a method to programmatically achieve this, preferably using Python? Both paid and unpaid solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Unfortunately, such feature is not available in Aspose.Words. The feature request is logged as **WORDSNET-13484**.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyNoskov for letting me know!